# Spark: best strategy for mapping a list of dataframes into a function

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, parallel-processing

Lets say I have a huge dataframe that can be split into smaller subsets by a given key/id.

I need to pass each subset to a function to get my job/calculations done.

Right now, this works:

```
def my_func_v1(id, df=df):
    mask = df.id_column == id
    subset = df.loc[mask, :]

    # make my calculations
    ....
    return my_result

sc = spark.sparkContext

list_of_ids = df.id_column.unique().tolist()
rdd = sc.parallelize(list_of_ids)

all_results = rdd.map(my_func_v1).collect()
```

But is this the best strategy? I mean, it looks like the original huge dataframe will be passed for each worker on the cluster.

What I wanted to do:

```
# create a list of subsets throught generators
list_of_subsets = (df[df.id_column == id] for id in list_of_ids)

def my_func_v2(subset):
    # make my calculations
    ....
    return my_result

rdd = sc.parallelize(list_of_subsets)
all_results = rdd.map(my_func_v2).collect()
```

Passing smaller subsets to spark map makes more sense to me.

The problem is: it won't work. The job won't start.

What am I missing? Am I looking at this in the right way?

--------- UPDATES -----------

Today the cluster was in a good mood and my_func_v2 worked too

BUT it took twice the time for creating the rdd

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(list_of_subsets)
```

and twice the time to map it

```
all_results = rdd.map(my_func_v2).collect()
```

Comment: You’re trying to filter the dataframe for a (very small) subset many times. Can your calculations (which you’re not showing) not simply be distributed over the entire dataframe? You’ll get much better performance using either groupBy or groupByKey (or any of the *ByKey methods). Without more details about your calculations, it’s hard to give better advice.

Comment: its a lot o ETL stuff based of some evaluations, returning another dataframe. Unfortulately this is not the typical groupby operation.

Comment: Also, please note that filtering the dataframe on the function works. I wanted to do something better than that.

Comment: Which is why I'm asking if you can't give more details about the ETL job. I've written dozens of Spark jobs and if groupBy doesn't quite work (because you’d need to use an aggregation function), groupByKey and mapValues likely could.